# Zooming an Image in ImageView (javafx)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I'm trying to zoom with a slider a selected image in ImageView. The only thing that I am able to do is to resize whole ImageView with the image in it. But this is not what i am searching for. I want to zoom only the image with ImageView having the same size. It should be a demonstration of a focal length. I'm using also scene builder.I'm only beginner in all of this, so I would really appreciate your help. Here's what I have.

```
public void openImage(ActionEvent event) {

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File f = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (f != null) {
        System.out.println(f.toURI().toString());
        Obrazok = new Image(f.toURI().toString());          
        imageView.setImage(Obrazok);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true); 

    }
}
public void setOnZoom (MouseEvent e){

    imageView.scaleXProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
    imageView.scaleYProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
    Rectangle2D viewpoint = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, Obrazok.getRequestedHeight(), Obrazok.getRequestedWidth());
    imageView.setViewport(viewpoint);
    imageView.setViewport(viewpoint);
    imageView.setImage(Obrazok);
}
```

Comment: Don't scale the image view; just change the viewport so that it refers to a different (typically smaller) portion of the image. The [documentation for `ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) has a basic example of this.

Answer (score 8):

i'm not really sure what you wanted to do ! and i kind of used James_D suggestion

alright i'm a Beginner too and it took me almost two hours to write this for you, hope anyone read this and find it useful

i only added ExtensionFilters for png and jpg but you can add any extension that is supported by javaFx

(i used sliders instead of scrollbars cause i hate dealing with scrollbars but i'm sure you can do it yourself)

[screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSCny.png)

[screenshot 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF6lY.png)

[screenshot 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQIpm.png)

[screenshot 04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK50k.png)

Update : now you can drag on the imageview to move the viewport

```
package application;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Main extends Application {
    static double initx;
    static double inity;
    static int height;
    static int width;
    public static String path;
    static Scene initialScene,View;
    static double offSetX,offSetY,zoomlvl;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {
        s.setResizable(false);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label hint = new Label("Select Your Image");
        TextField URL = new TextField();
        URL.setEditable(false);
        URL.setPrefWidth(350);

        Button browse = new Button("Browse");
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        ExtensionFilter png = new ExtensionFilter("png", "*.png");
        ExtensionFilter jpg = new ExtensionFilter("jpg", "*.jpg");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(png,jpg);
        browse.setOnAction(e->{
            URL.setText(fc.showOpenDialog(s).getAbsolutePath());
        });

        Button open = new Button("Open");
        open.setOnAction(e->{
            path = URL.getText();
            initView();
            s.setScene(View);
        });

        grid.add(hint, 0, 0);
        grid.add(URL, 1, 0);
        grid.add(browse, 2, 0);
        grid.add(open, 2, 1);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid,600,100);
        s.setScene(initialScene);
        s.show();
    }

    public static void initView(){
        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label title = new Label(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
        Image source = null;
        try {
            source = new Image(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView image = new ImageView(source);
        double ratio = source.getWidth()/source.getHeight();

        if(500/ratio < 500) {
            width=500;
            height=(int) (500/ratio);
        }else if(500*ratio < 500){
            height=500;
            width=(int) (500*ratio);
        }else {
            height=500;
            width=500;
        }
        image.setPreserveRatio(false);
        image.setFitWidth(width);
        image.setFitHeight(height);
        height = (int) source.getHeight();
        width = (int) source.getWidth();
        System.out.println("height = "+height+"\nwidth = "+width);
        HBox zoom = new HBox(10);
        zoom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Slider zoomLvl = new Slider();
        zoomLvl.setMax(4);
        zoomLvl.setMin(1);
        zoomLvl.setMaxWidth(200);
        zoomLvl.setMinWidth(200);
        Label hint = new Label("Zoom Level");
        Label value = new Label("1.0");

        offSetX = width/2;
        offSetY = height/2;



        zoom.getChildren().addAll(hint,zoomLvl,value);

        Slider Hscroll = new Slider();
        Hscroll.setMin(0);
        Hscroll.setMax(width);
        Hscroll.setMaxWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setMinWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setTranslateY(-20);
        Slider Vscroll = new Slider();
        Vscroll.setMin(0);
        Vscroll.setMax(height);
        Vscroll.setMaxHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setMinHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Vscroll.setTranslateX(-20);


        BorderPane imageView = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Hscroll, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Vscroll, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Hscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e->{
            offSetX = Hscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double)((int)(zoomlvl*10))/10;
            value.setText(newValue+"");
            if(offSetX<(width/newValue)/2) {
                offSetX = (width/newValue)/2;
            }
            if(offSetX>width-((width/newValue)/2)) {
                offSetX = width-((width/newValue)/2);
            }

            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX-((width/newValue)/2), offSetY-((height/newValue)/2), width/newValue, height/newValue));
        });
        Vscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e->{
            offSetY = height-Vscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double)((int)(zoomlvl*10))/10;
            value.setText(newValue+"");
            if(offSetY<(height/newValue)/2) {
                offSetY = (height/newValue)/2;
            }
            if(offSetY>height-((height/newValue)/2)) {
                offSetY = height-((height/newValue)/2);
            }
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX-((width/newValue)/2), offSetY-((height/newValue)/2), width/newValue, height/newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCenter(image);
        imageView.setTop(Hscroll);
        imageView.setRight(Vscroll);
        zoomLvl.valueProperty().addListener(e->{
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double)((int)(zoomlvl*10))/10;
            value.setText(newValue+"");
            if(offSetX<(width/newValue)/2) {
                offSetX = (width/newValue)/2;
            }
            if(offSetX>width-((width/newValue)/2)) {
                offSetX = width-((width/newValue)/2);
            }
            if(offSetY<(height/newValue)/2) {
                offSetY = (height/newValue)/2;
            }
            if(offSetY>height-((height/newValue)/2)) {
                offSetY = height-((height/newValue)/2);
            }
            Hscroll.setValue(offSetX);
            Vscroll.setValue(height-offSetY);
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX-((width/newValue)/2), offSetY-((height/newValue)/2), width/newValue, height/newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        image.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseReleased(e->{
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            Hscroll.setValue(Hscroll.getValue()+(initx - e.getSceneX()));
            Vscroll.setValue(Vscroll.getValue()-(inity - e.getSceneY()));
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(title,imageView,zoom);

        View = new Scene(root,(image.getFitWidth())+70,(image.getFitHeight())+150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037270/230513) illustrates zooming and panning an image using sliders, the variant below focuses on a more basic approach that may be easier to adapt to other use cases. It leverages  [`ImageView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) scaling to zoom and [`ScrollPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) mouse handing to pan.

In summary, the application constructs an `ImageView` from an `Image` read from the selected file, altering the cursor to indicate dragging with a closed hand. The `ImageView` is then used to construct a `ScrollPane`, for which the `pannable` property is enabled; scrolling starts out centered. A `Slider` controls the zoom level, and its listener alters the view's `fitWidth` property accordingly, while preserving the image's aspect ratio. By saving and restoring the scroll pane's scroll bar settings, zooming stays centered on the view.

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328643/230513 */
public class PanZoomImage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        var fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        if (file != null) {
            var image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file));
            var view = new ImageView(image);
            view.setPreserveRatio(true);
            view.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                view.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
            });
            view.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                view.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
            });
            view.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
                view.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
            });
            view.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
                view.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            });
            var sp = new ScrollPane(view);
            sp.setPannable(true);
            sp.setHvalue(0.5);
            sp.setVvalue(0.5);
            var slider = new Slider(1.0, 3.0, 1.0);
            slider.setBlockIncrement(0.1);
            slider.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldV, newV) -> {
                var x = sp.getHvalue();
                var y = sp.getVvalue();
                view.setFitWidth(image.getWidth() * newV.doubleValue());
                sp.setHvalue(x);
                sp.setVvalue(y);
            });
            var root = new BorderPane(sp);
            root.setBottom(slider);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 320, 240));
            stage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```