# Draw a line on an image javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a map image in my java project when the user clicks on two cities I want to draw a line on the map image between these two cities, so if I do any effects like zooming the lines get affected too not just the image. how can I do that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: @azro I have been trying to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687994/zooming-an-image-in-imageview-javafx to find a way to solve my problem but I had no luck, because I am new to JavaFX, and I haven't found anything useful on the internet I thought the stack overflow community would help that's all.

Answer (score 2):

> so if I do any effects like zooming the lines get affected too not just the image.

Put the map image and the line in the same `Parent` (e.g. `Group`, `Pane`, etc).  Then apply the zoom to the `Parent` `Node`, and not the map image directly.