# Byte[] to ImageView Conversion

Tags: java, image, javafx, byte, blob

Looking for ways to print an image on the screen, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037270/230513) class, which basically does everything I need.

```
package manipulaimagem;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 *
 * @author Giovani
 */
public class ManipulaImagemOP extends Application {

    static double initx;
    static double inity;
    static int height;
    static int width;
    public static String path;
    static Scene initialScene, View;
    static double offSetX, offSetY, zoomlvl;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {
        s.setResizable(false);
       
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label hint = new Label("Select Your Image");
        TextField URL = new TextField();
        URL.setEditable(false);
        URL.setPrefWidth(350);

        Button browse = new Button("Browse");
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        ExtensionFilter png = new ExtensionFilter("png", "*.png");
        ExtensionFilter jpg = new ExtensionFilter("jpg", "*.jpg");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(png, jpg);
        browse.setOnAction(e -> {
            URL.setText(fc.showOpenDialog(s).getAbsolutePath());
        });

        Button open = new Button("Open");
        open.setOnAction(e -> {
            path = URL.getText();
            initView();
            s.setScene(View);
        });
        
        grid.add(hint, 0, 0);
        grid.add(URL, 1, 0);
        grid.add(browse, 2, 0);
        grid.add(open, 2, 1);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);
        s.setScene(initialScene);
        s.show();
        
    }

    public static void initView() {
        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label title = new Label("Teste de Título");
        Image source = null;
        try {
            source = new Image(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView image = new ImageView(source);
        double ratio = source.getWidth() / source.getHeight();

        if (500 / ratio < 500) {
            width = 500;
            height = (int) (500 / ratio);
        } else if (500 * ratio < 500) {
            height = 500;
            width = (int) (500 * ratio);
        } else {
            height = 500;
            width = 500;
        }
        image.setPreserveRatio(false);
        image.setFitWidth(width);
        image.setFitHeight(height);
        height = (int) source.getHeight();
        width = (int) source.getWidth();
        System.out.println("height = " + height + "\nwidth = " + width);
        HBox zoom = new HBox(10);
        zoom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Slider zoomLvl = new Slider();
        zoomLvl.setMax(4);
        zoomLvl.setMin(1);
        zoomLvl.setMaxWidth(200);
        zoomLvl.setMinWidth(200);
        Label hint = new Label("Zoom Level");
        Label value = new Label("1.0");

        offSetX = width / 2;
        offSetY = height / 2;

        zoom.getChildren().addAll(hint, zoomLvl, value);

        Slider Hscroll = new Slider();
        Hscroll.setMin(0);
        Hscroll.setMax(width);
        Hscroll.setMaxWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setMinWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setTranslateY(-20);
        Slider Vscroll = new Slider();
        Vscroll.setMin(0);
        Vscroll.setMax(height);
        Vscroll.setMaxHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setMinHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Vscroll.setTranslateX(-20);

        BorderPane imageView = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Hscroll, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Vscroll, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Hscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetX = Hscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }

            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        Vscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetY = height - Vscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCenter(image);
        imageView.setTop(Hscroll);
        imageView.setRight(Vscroll);
        zoomLvl.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            Hscroll.setValue(offSetX);
            Vscroll.setValue(height - offSetY);
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        image.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            Hscroll.setValue(Hscroll.getValue() + (initx - e.getSceneX()));
            Vscroll.setValue(Vscroll.getValue() - (inity - e.getSceneY()));
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(title, imageView, zoom);

        View = new Scene(root, (image.getFitWidth()) + 70, (image.getFitHeight()) + 150);
    } 
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I adapted it to my project this way, I'm searching the database, and exporting the image, for later import.

The export is happening correctly, it generates the image in the folder, however when importing, the screen opens empty and does not show the image.It does not show errors in the console.

```
package eletronicstorefx;

import dao.EntradaDocumentoDAO;
import static eletronicstorefx.EletronicStoreFX.codEntrada;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.EntradaDocumentos;

/**
 *
 * @author Giovani
 */
public class ManipulaImagem extends Application {

    static double initx;
    static double inity;
    static int height;
    static int width;
    public static String path = ("C:/Electronics_StoreSC/NotasFiscais/nf.jpg");
    static Scene initialScene, View;
    static double offSetX, offSetY, zoomlvl;
    public static byte[] byte_array;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) throws IOException {

    }
   
    public void testaInici() throws IOException {

        EntradaDocumentoDAO entDocDAO = new EntradaDocumentoDAO();
        EntradaDocumentos entDoc = new EntradaDocumentos();
        entDoc = entDocDAO.getNotaFiscal(codEntrada);
        byte_array = entDoc.getNOTA_FISCAL();
        ByteToImage();

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        initView();
        stage.setScene(View);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);
        stage.setScene(initialScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void ByteToImage() {
        byte[] imgBytes = byte_array;        
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            fos.write(imgBytes);
            FileDescriptor fd = fos.getFD();
            fos.flush();
            fd.sync();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void initView() {

        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label title = new Label("");
        Image source = null;
        try {
            source = new Image(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView image = new ImageView(source);
        double ratio = source.getWidth() / source.getHeight();

        if (500 / ratio < 500) {
            width = 500;
            height = (int) (500 / ratio);
        } else if (500 * ratio < 500) {
            height = 500;
            width = (int) (500 * ratio);
        } else {
            height = 500;
            width = 500;
        }
        image.setPreserveRatio(false);
        image.setFitWidth(width);
        image.setFitHeight(height);
        height = (int) source.getHeight();
        width = (int) source.getWidth();
        System.out.println("height = " + height + "\nwidth = " + width);
        HBox zoom = new HBox(10);
        zoom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Slider zoomLvl = new Slider();
        zoomLvl.setMax(4);
        zoomLvl.setMin(1);
        zoomLvl.setMaxWidth(200);
        zoomLvl.setMinWidth(200);
        Label hint = new Label("Zoom Level");
        Label value = new Label("1.0");

        offSetX = width / 2;
        offSetY = height / 2;

        zoom.getChildren().addAll(hint, zoomLvl, value);

        Slider Hscroll = new Slider();
        Hscroll.setMin(0);
        Hscroll.setMax(width);
        Hscroll.setMaxWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setMinWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setTranslateY(-20);
        Slider Vscroll = new Slider();
        Vscroll.setMin(0);
        Vscroll.setMax(height);
        Vscroll.setMaxHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setMinHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Vscroll.setTranslateX(-20);

        BorderPane imageView = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Hscroll, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Vscroll, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Hscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetX = Hscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }

            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        Vscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetY = height - Vscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCenter(image);
        imageView.setTop(Hscroll);
        imageView.setRight(Vscroll);
        zoomLvl.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            Hscroll.setValue(offSetX);
            Vscroll.setValue(height - offSetY);
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        image.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        });
        image.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            Hscroll.setValue(Hscroll.getValue() + (initx - e.getSceneX()));
            Vscroll.setValue(Vscroll.getValue() - (inity - e.getSceneY()));
            initx = e.getSceneX();
            inity = e.getSceneY();
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(title, imageView, zoom);

        View = new Scene(root, (image.getFitWidth()) + 70, (image.getFitHeight()) + 150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to convert Byte[] to ImagemView without exporting and importing? What's wrong with not showing the image on the screen? I searched the internet and didn't find a conversion method.

Reproduzi o mesmo código que tenho, basta alterar o caminho da imagem para testar.

Ele até exibe o tamanho da imagem, só não mostra na tela.

```
package stackproject;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author Giovani
 */
public class StackProject extends Application {

    static double initx;
    static double inity;
    static int height;
    static int width;
    public static String path = ("C:/Electronics_StoreSC/NotasFiscais/nf.jpg");
    static Scene initialScene, View;
    static double offSetX, offSetY, zoomlvl;
    public static byte[] byteArray;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            imageToByte(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);
        stage.setScene(initialScene);
        stage.show();

        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label title = new Label("Teste de Titulo");
        Image source = null;
        try {
            source = new Image(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView image = new ImageView(source);
        double ratio = source.getWidth() / source.getHeight();

        if (500 / ratio < 500) {
            width = 500;
            height = (int) (500 / ratio);
        } else if (500 * ratio < 500) {
            height = 500;
            width = (int) (500 * ratio);
        } else {
            height = 500;
            width = 500;
        }
        image.setPreserveRatio(false);
        image.setFitWidth(width);
        image.setFitHeight(height);
        height = (int) source.getHeight();
        width = (int) source.getWidth();
        System.out.println("height = " + height + "\nwidth = " + width);
        HBox zoom = new HBox(10);
        zoom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Slider zoomLvl = new Slider();
        zoomLvl.setMax(4);
        zoomLvl.setMin(1);
        zoomLvl.setMaxWidth(200);
        zoomLvl.setMinWidth(200);
        Label hint = new Label("Zoom Level");
        Label value = new Label("1.0");

        offSetX = width / 2;
        offSetY = height / 2;

        zoom.getChildren().addAll(hint, zoomLvl, value);

        Slider Hscroll = new Slider();
        Hscroll.setMin(0);
        Hscroll.setMax(width);
        Hscroll.setMaxWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setMinWidth(image.getFitWidth());
        Hscroll.setTranslateY(-20);
        Slider Vscroll = new Slider();
        Vscroll.setMin(0);
        Vscroll.setMax(height);
        Vscroll.setMaxHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setMinHeight(image.getFitHeight());
        Vscroll.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Vscroll.setTranslateX(-20);

        BorderPane imageView = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Hscroll, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(Vscroll, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Hscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetX = Hscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }

            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        Vscroll.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            offSetY = height - Vscroll.getValue();
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCenter(image);
        imageView.setTop(Hscroll);
        imageView.setRight(Vscroll);
        zoomLvl.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            zoomlvl = zoomLvl.getValue();
            double newValue = (double) ((int) (zoomlvl * 10)) / 10;
            value.setText(newValue + "");
            if (offSetX < (width / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetX = (width / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetX > width - ((width / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetX = width - ((width / newValue) / 2);
            }
            if (offSetY < (height / newValue) / 2) {
                offSetY = (height / newValue) / 2;
            }
            if (offSetY > height - ((height / newValue) / 2)) {
                offSetY = height - ((height / newValue) / 2);
            }
            Hscroll.setValue(offSetX);
            Vscroll.setValue(height - offSetY);
            image.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offSetX - ((width / newValue) / 2), offSetY - ((height / newValue) / 2), width / newValue, height / newValue));
        });
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
```

Comment: Sorry, I put the same code twice, instead of my adapted one, I corrected it.

Comment: And: what format is the image in? What is actually in the byte array data you get? Can you open the images from the files you create using system tools (preview on mac or whatever windows uses these days)?

Comment: You could just read from a `ByteArrayInputStream`. By the way, what you have is a `byte[]`, not a `Byte[]`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: When I call my class, I invoke testInici().

Comment: @GiovaniJulioBoaretto Then why is it a subclass of `Application`?

Comment: And doesn’t `testaInici()` just display an empty `GridPane`? What am I missing?

Comment: James_D não sei o que estou fazendo incorretamente, deveria aparecer a imagem, bem como a opção de zoom.

Comment: I commented below an equal functional code for testing.

Comment: Just read the code you posted. You have `GridPane grid = new GridPane();`. You never add anything to the grid pane, so it is an empty grid pane, with nothing in it. Then you do `initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100)`, so `initialScene` is a scene containing an empty grid pane, so it's basically an empty scene. Then you do `stage.setScene(initialScene)`, so the stage is now displaying an empty scene. What are you expecting to see with that code?

Comment: So basically your question is: here is some code displaying an empty `GridPane`. Why can't I see an image in it?

Comment: Please don't neglect to cite the original source as [required](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Answer (score 1):

The window is empty because you explicitly write code to display an empty window:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    /*

     ...

    */


    stage.setResizable(false);

    // The next four lines create a GridPane,
    // and configure it in terms of gaps between its
    // components and how it is aligned:

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(20);
    grid.setVgap(20);
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    // You have not put any content in the grid pane,
    // so it is still empty


    // The next line creates a scene containing the empty grid pane.
    // Since the grid pane is empty, the scene does not display anything.

    initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);

    // This sets the scene of the stage (the window) to the (empty) scene:
    stage.setScene(initialScene);

    // And now you show the window, which is displaying an empty scene:
    stage.show();


    /*

        ...

    */
}
```

Comment: OK, but how do I get the content on the screen?

Comment: You put the content in the scene graph.  Here is [hello, world](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm) app, it puts content in the scene.  Do the same thing.

Comment: @Homer: This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328643/230513) may be a easier to adapt.

Comment: @trashgod, in this example what does var mean?

Comment: @Homer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/language/toc.htm#JSLAN-GUID-7D5FDD65-ACE4-4B3C-80F4-CC01CBD211A4

Comment: Got it, I changed the respective variables and the code worked.

Comment: I managed to make the trashgod example project run, however I am not able to understand in my project what is needed for the imageView and the Sliders to appear. I need to add them to the scene, but how do I do that? James' explanation was very good, I could understand the code I found, but I can't understand how to add the elements in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). Just replace:

```
new Image(new FileInputStream(path))
```

With:

```
new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte_array))
```

(Although you should probably also replace `byte_array` with `byteArray` to conform to Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Note this will only work if the image data are stored in a supported format (png, jpg, etc)

Comment: @James_D It is apparently already working for OP when storing to a file and then reading that file back in, so it must be.

Comment: That’s not how I understand the question. The code that works is code the OP found online which allows the user to select existing image files and display them. The code the OP wrote saves image data from a database and tries to open them and display them. That code isn’t working, but it seems it’s because the code simply doesn’t display anything. I agree that if the code does work, your approach is better, but it doesn’t actually solve the “nothing is displayed” problem, which is caused by, well, simply not displaying anything.

Comment: Anyway, the point is that I don't think the OP actually says anywhere that the image files created by dumping the database data to them have been successfully opened anywhere. I may be wrong: the whole question just seems very confused.

Comment: If the `byte[]` is _not_ in a supported image file format, but is instead the raw pixel data, then it might be possible to use `WritableImage` and `PixelWriter`.

Answer (score -1):

The code works, I debugged more carefully and realized that the error was only in the order of the lines. I would add the scene to the Stage with the image, then add a new empty Stage.

```
public void testaInici() throws IOException {

        EntradaDocumentoDAO entDocDAO = new EntradaDocumentoDAO();
        EntradaDocumentos entDoc = new EntradaDocumentos();
        entDoc = entDocDAO.getNotaFiscal(codEntrada);
        byte_array = entDoc.getNOTA_FISCAL();
        ByteToImage();

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        initView();
        stage.setScene(View);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);
        stage.setScene(initialScene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

The correct one should be:

```
public void testaInici() throws IOException {

        EntradaDocumentoDAO entDocDAO = new EntradaDocumentoDAO();
        EntradaDocumentos entDoc = new EntradaDocumentos();
        entDoc = entDocDAO.getNotaFiscal(codEntrada);
        byte_array = entDoc.getNOTA_FISCAL();
        ByteToImage();

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        initialScene = new Scene(grid, 600, 100);
        stage.setScene(initialScene);
        stage.show();
        
        initView();
        stage.setScene(View);

    }
    
Thanks to everyone who helped.
```